# Toshiba Satellite L745-S4110 brightness keys not working

Tags: brightness, toshiba

My brightness keys don't work on Ubuntu 12.10.
It's weird because they only worked 1 time, and I was like "I guess it fixed itself," but it hasn't worked since then..

I get this from in syslog:

```
Dec 14 16:14:08 toshi kernel: [ 2315.861338] atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0xee on isa0060/serio0).
Dec 14 16:14:08 toshi kernel: [ 2315.861342] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e06e <keycode>' to make it known.
Dec 14 16:14:08 toshi kernel: [ 2315.934813] atkbd serio0: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0xee on isa0060/serio0).
Dec 14 16:14:08 toshi kernel: [ 2315.934817] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e06e <keycode>' to make it known.
Dec 14 16:14:08 toshi kernel: [ 2316.097483] atkbd serio0: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0x55 on isa0060/serio0).
Dec 14 16:14:08 toshi kernel: [ 2316.097493] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes 55 <keycode>' to make it known.
```

Also it works to change brightness in *Brightness and Lock* but it's very inconvenient to have to use that.

Comment: Have you tried the `acpi_osi=` as a kernel parameter via grub ?

Comment: The thing is the volume works [FN + 3, FN + 4].  So I know the FN button is working.  but what do I put it equal to? `acpi_osi=Linux` ?

Comment: The `acpi_osi=` is more effective , let the kernel decide the equal .. do not force it :-) .

Comment: Well I tried both ways and it did not fix it.  I posted on ubuntuforums.

Comment: Well , I cannot login to Ubuntuforums due to the recent problem with login (I have only a launchpad account) , so we cannot discuss it there. You can try another kernel or you can fill a bug about this. Probably a problem with ACPI. Usually such problems corrected with one of the above-mentioned parameters, but your situation seems little more difficult.

Comment: I can confirm that acpi_osi= made brightness keys work on a Toshiba U940

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"` in /etc/default/grub.

Then run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: I tried directly booting with those parameters by pressing **E** in GRUB, putting them after **quiet splash** but it did not work.  I even tried **acpi_osi=** as in the comment by @NikTh, but that didn't work either.  So today, before I tried this, after I resumed my laptop from suspend, the brightness keys worked!  I rebooted and it stopped working. I tried sleeping, and waking up, it still did not work.. :(

Comment: If you modify grub by pressing e, the settings are not permanent. If you modify grub the way I said in my answer the settings will be permanent.

Comment: It would be no good to have it permanent, because **it did not fix the problem**.

Answer (score 0):

The messages in syslog point to the problem described here:
[Finding raw scan codes - PS/2 keyboards](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Multimedia_Keys#Finding_raw_scan_codes_-_PS.2F2_keyboards)
It is a long howto with much details.

The solution is tersely documented in the file:

```
/usr/share/doc/udev/README.keymap.txt.gz
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, however it did not work for me. :(